# Databse getting locked when trying to update and insert

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

When i try to insert or update, database gets locked randomly. I am giving the code that I am using. Kindly let me know if something else needs to be done apart from this.

I read some where this issue occurs because of open and close functionality of database. Please let me know what the issue is?

```
-(BOOL)createDB : (const char *)str {
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SpotLogic.db"]];
BOOL isSuccess = YES;
// NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
        const char *sql_stmt = str;
        if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
            != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return  isSuccess;
    }
    else {
        isSuccess = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
return isSuccess;
}


- (BOOL)deleteData:(NSString *)deleteSql
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SpotLogic.db"]];
dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *insert_stmt = [deleteSql UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        return YES;
        NSLog(@"deleted");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not deleted");
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return NO;
}


- (BOOL)insertData:(NSString *)insertSQL
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SpotLogic.db"]];
dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            return YES;
            NSLog(@"inserted");
        } 
        else {
            NSLog(@"Not inserted");
            return NO;
        }
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
return NO;
}


- (sqlite3_stmt *)fetchData:(NSString *)fetchSQL
{
NSLog(@"%@",fetchSQL);
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SpotLogic.db"]];
 // array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *fetch_stmt = [fetchSQL UTF8String];
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, fetch_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
return statement;
   }


- (BOOL)update:(NSString *)insertSQL
{
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
  // Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"SpotLogic.db"]];
 dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        return YES;
        NSLog(@"inserted");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Not inserted");
        return NO;
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
}
return NO;
}
```

I actually found the problem. My database gets locked when I run this code.

```
 for(int i = 0 ; i < meeting_ids.count ; i ++){
    statement = [[DataManger getSharedInstance] fetchData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT red_flag FROM meeting_question WHERE meeting_id = '%@'",[meeting_ids objectAtIndex:i]]];

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        char *field1=(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        NSString *name =[[ NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field1];
        NSLog(@"%@",name);
        if([name isEqualToString:@"1"]){
            [red_flag replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"1"];
            break;
        }
    }
   }
```

This while with for loop is the reason. 
I have to get 'red_flag' from all the meetings with meeting ids in 'meeting_ids' array.
Any other way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

If you opens database every time, then close it also every time.

So, write ...

```
sqlite3_close(database);
```

this line in all function.

Comment: at last in if condition of sqlite3_open. because if it is open then and then close only

Comment: I actually found the problem. My database gets locked when I run this code.

Comment: I can't post the code here, I have edited the queston. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

After running statement please use these two statement for reset and finalize statement then close data base.

```
sqlite3_reset(statement);
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
sqlite3_close(database);
```